# Table view cells are flickering while reloading the table view cells

Tags: ios, uikit, bluetooth-lowenergy, swift5

Table view cells are flickering while reloading the individual cells. I want to reload the table view cells whenever BLE callbacks comes. this is working as expected. But, if scroll and hold the table view, that time view cells are flickering.

Same scenario , I have tried with static data without BLE scan, I am running the timer each and every second and reloading the table cells, this time cells are not flickering. When I Scroll and hold the table view, I observe that timer is stopping until I release the table view.

But In BLE scenario, If scroll and hold also BLE callbacks are coming continuously.

Please help me to handle BLE callbacks case, to stop the table view cells flickering at time of scroll and hold the table view.

```
reloadTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(reloadTableViewCells), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc func reloadTableViewCells(_ name: String) {
    if let index = myArray.firstIndex(where: {name == $0}) {
          self.myArray[index] = name
          self.tableViewRx.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .none)
    } else {
         myArray.append(name)
         self.reloadTableView()
    }
}
```

```
func scanForBLEDevices() {
    scanBleDevices(allowDuplicates: true, peripheralUUIDString: nil, callback: reloadTableViewCellsOnBleScan)
reloadTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(reloadTableViewCells), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func reloadTableViewCellsOnBleScan(_ name: String) {
    if let index = myArray.firstIndex(where: {name == $0}) {
          self.myArray[index] = name
          self.tableViewRx.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .none)
    } else {
         myArray.append(name)
         self.reloadTableView()
    }
}
```

expected results is, table view cells should stop flickering when I scroll and hold the table view.

Comment: You should only reload the tableview if your entire data model has changed. If there is only a change to one row, just reload or insert that row

Comment: When scan callback gives same name once again reload the particular row or different name insert new row. I am doing same way what you suggested, but cells are flickering when scroll the table view up and hold it.

Comment: So you have eliminated all of the calls to `reloadTableView`?

Comment: Not all calls, depend on BLE callback response.

Comment: You need to get rid of all of them. Either reload the row or insert the new row. No need to reload the whole table

Comment: I tried what you suggested, But it is not working.